Menu closed on click any menu item but requirement is, if clicked on item menu should open
Refs: https://material.angular.io/cdk/menu/examples
Angular cdk menu closed on click any menu item but requirement is, if clicked on item menu should open and should close on clicked outside the menu or on esc
Note - we can't use https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview because it's not provide the accessibility. If we use this arrow key down or up scrolling main window while we should jump to opened menu item and other requirements also not full filled using this.
If anyone has any solution, please share
Thanks!
Code -


import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CdkMenu, CdkMenuItem, CdkMenuTrigger} from '@angular/cdk/menu';

/** @title Menu with Standalone Trigger. */
@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-menu-standalone-menu-example',
  styleUrl: 'cdk-menu-standalone-menu-example.css',
  templateUrl: 'cdk-menu-standalone-menu-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CdkMenuTrigger, CdkMenu, CdkMenuItem],
})
export class CdkMenuStandaloneMenuExample {}
.example-menu {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 180px;
  max-width: 280px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 6px 0;
}

.example-menu-item,
.example-standalone-trigger {
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;

  user-select: none;
  min-width: 64px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0 16px;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
}

.example-menu-item:hover {
  background-color: rgb(208, 208, 208);
}

.example-menu-item:active {
  background-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);
}

.example-standalone-item {
  background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);
}
.example-standalone-item:hover {
  background-color: rgb(208, 208, 208);
}
.example-standalone-item[aria-expanded='true'] {
  background-color: rgb(208, 208, 208);
}
<button [cdkMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="example-standalone-trigger">Click me!</button>

<ng-template #menu>
  <div class="example-menu" cdkMenu>
    <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Refresh</button>
    <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Settings</button>
    <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Help</button>
    <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Sign out</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>




Why do you want to keep the menu open ? Do you want to open/display another menu based on the interaction with this menu ? Does using nested menu fulfill your requirements ?

@Hujaakbar Requirement - On click menu item dialog open and on close dialog focus should go that particular menu item from where dialog opened

I think as a workaround, you can re-open the menu when the dialog is closed. It is not a neat solution, but works.

Yes @Hujaakbar, I already tried this approach but it's create accessibility issue (in this case focus always goes to 1st menu item)

Any idea how to focus programmatically particular menu item? I used  CdkMenuItem focus method but it's not working e.g. @ViewChild('settings') settings: CdkMenuItem | undefined; and this.settings?.focus() but not works

In your case, as a workaround, you can reopen the menu when a dialog closes.
Apparently you tried but encountered an error.

Any idea how to focus programmatically particular menu item? I used CdkMenuItem focus method but it's not working e.g. @ViewChild('settings') settings: CdkMenuItem | undefined; and this.settings?.focus() but not works

The reason why it is not working is because of below line, more precisely because you are using @ViewChild.
@ViewChild('settings') settings: CdkMenuItem | undefined;

When you initiate you component, it can't find your menu item since menu is not open (not in the DOM), and settings becomes undefined.
There is a signal based alternative to @ViewChild, viewChield function. You should use that. \

viewChield creates a child query in your component by declaring a class field and initializing it with the viewChild() function.

Best thing about it is when menu items are added to the DOM, signal updates and refers to the CdkMenuItem.
Code:
html template
<button [cdkMenuTriggerFor]="menu" 
#tr="cdkMenuTriggerFor"
class="example-standalone-trigger">
   Click me!
</button>


<ng-template #menu>
  <div class="example-menu" cdkMenu>
    <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem
     #refresh="cdkMenuItem"
        (click)="myMethod()">
      Refresh
    </button>
    <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Settings</button>
    <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Help</button>
    <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Sign out</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>


Explanation:
Use variables to refer to CdkTrigger button and CdkmenuItem.
Note: variables should refer to exactly cdkMenuTriggerFor and cdkMenuItem directives, otherwise they refer to underlying html element and solution will not work.
Component class:
import { CdkMenu, CdkMenuItem, CdkMenuTrigger } from '@angular/cdk/menu';
import { Component, Signal, viewChild} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CdkMenuTrigger,
    CdkMenu,
    CdkMenuItem,
  ],
  templateUrl: './my-html.html',
  styleUrl: './my-styles.scss',
})
export class MyComponent {

  protected trigger = viewChild<CdkMenuTrigger>('tr');
  protected refreshMenuItem = viewChild<CdkMenuItem>('refresh');

  dialogClosed() {
    this.trigger()?.open(); // reopen the closed menu
    this.refreshMenuItem()?.focus(); // focus on the item
  }

  myMethod(){ 
   // your logic when the menuItem is clicked
 }

}


Explanation:
We are using vewChild signal based function to get trigger and refresh menu item.
When the dialog closes, you should call dialogClosed method, it in turn reopens the menu and focuses on the refresh menu item.
You can implement your logic yourself to decide which menu item to focus after dialog closes. Probably you can pass along some data to dialogClosed function to determine the menu item to focus on.

Thanks for the reply but I am facing error on CdkMenuTrigger -  TS2558: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1. 24   protected trigger3 = ViewChild('tr');

And if use smal v viewChild oit's showing can't find name 'viewChild' - protected trigger3 = viewChild('tr'); I am not sure whate the issue, could you please review again. Thanks!

I updated answer. Basically, it is viewChild function (lower case v), and you should import it from angular/core like this: import { Component, Signal, viewChild} from '@angular/core';

Facing error I am not sure if still missing something - Error: src/app/normal-menu/normal-menu.component.ts:2:51 - error TS2724: '"@angular/core"' has no exported member named 'viewChild'. Did you mean 'ViewChild'?
2 import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, ViewChild, viewChild } from '@angular/core';
~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts:9314:22
9314 export declare const ViewChild: ViewChildDecorator;
~~~~~~~~~
'ViewChild' is declared here.

which version of angular are you using ?

@angular/core": "^15.2.0", "@angular/cli": "~15.2.0",

viewChild function returns a signal, probably it is not available in v15. If you can, upgrade your angular version, otherwise above code doesn't work

Okay Thanks for the update
