How to open a particular menu programmatically if more than one menu element - angular cdk menu
How to open a particular menu programmatically if more than one menu element - angular cdk menu
As given below code for menu 1 and menu 2, I need to create @ViewChild(CdkMenuTrigger) trigger: CdkMenuTrigger; for menu 2 programmatically but by default it capture menu 1 always, so how we can create object for particular menu programmatically?
Please note both code in same file..
For Refs - Open Angular CDK Menu programatically
Code Menu 1-


<button [cdkMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="example-standalone-trigger">Click me!</button>

<ng-template #menu>
  <div class="example-menu" cdkMenu>
    <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Refresh</button>
    <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem #settings>Settings</button>
    <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Help</button>
    <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Sign out</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>



Code Menu 2 -


<button [cdkMenuTriggerFor]="menu2" class="example-standalone-trigger">Click me!</button>

<ng-template #menu2>
  <div class="example-menu" cdkMenu>
    <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Menu Item1</button>
    <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Menu Item2</button>
    <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Menu Item3</button>
    <button class="example-menu-item" cdkMenuItem>Menu Item4</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>




Can you detail the question a bit more?
And explain what is the difference between the first snippet and the second one

As given code for menu 1 and menu 2, I need to create @ViewChild(CdkMenuTrigger) trigger: CdkMenuTrigger; for menu 2 programmatically but by default it capture menu 1 always, so how we can create object for particular menu programmatically?

Have you tried to use ViewChildren to query both menus? https://v17.angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren


I need to create @ViewChild(CdkMenuTrigger) trigger: CdkMenuTrigger; for menu 2 programmatically but by default it capture menu 1 always, so how we can create object for particular menu programmatically?

So, whenever you try to get a trigger for menu2, you are ending up getting a trigger for menu1. It is what I understood from your comments.
The reason for that is @ViewChild looks for the first element or the directive matching the selector in the view DOM.
The First Approach
You can use @ViewChildren instead.
@ViewChildren return a QueryList object that contains the query results (all the triggers).
To get a particular trigger, you can use get(index) method.
@ViewChildren(MatMenuTrigger) triggers: QueryList<MatMenuTrigger>;


 someMethod() {
    this.triggers.get(1).openMenu();
  }


The Second Approach
If you do not want to use @ViewChildren, you can still keep using @ViewChild but you should distinguish your second trigger.
Among others, below selectors are supported by @ViewChild

Any class with the @Component or @Directive decorator
A template reference variable as a string

So,
html template:
<button 
#menuTrigger2="matMenuTrigger"
[cdkMenuTriggerFor]="menu2" 
class="example-standalone-trigger">
   Click me!
</button>


component.ts:
@ViewChild('menuTrigger2') trigger!: MatMenuTrigger;

 someMethod() {
    this.trigger!.openMenu();
  }


Thanks @Hujaakbar, could please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79017179/menu-closed-on-click-any-menu-item-but-requirement-is-if-clicked-on-item-menu-s, it's not working as per requirements. if any solution or suggestion , please share

@arun did my above answer solve your question posted. If so, please accept the answer.

Accepted. Could you please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79017179/menu-closed-on-click-any-menu-item-but-requirement-is-if-clicked-on-item-menu-s

Any idea how to focus programmatically particular menu item?

Tried CdkMenuItem focus method but it's not working e.g. @ViewChild('settings') settings: CdkMenuItem | undefined; and this.settings?.focus()

@arun I will take a look at your second post/issue a little later

Sure @Hujaakbar Thanks!

2nd approach not working for cdk menu (i.e. not mat menu)

change #menuTrigger2="matMenuTrigger" to #menuTrigger2="cdkMenuTrigger"

Not working! error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'cdkMenuTrigger'.
27 <button class="example-standalone-trigger" #menuTrigger2="cdkMenuTrigger" [cdkMenuTriggerFor]="menu2" >Click me2!

sorry, cdkMenuTriggerFor

Great! working now Thanks! @Hujaakbar. did you check how to focus particular menu item programmatically? I need this help to solve my all problem

Using @ViewChildren(CdkMenuTrigger) triggerMenuContainer!: QueryList; able to get particular menu CdkMenuTrigger object.
e.g. this.triggerMenuContainer.get(1)?.open();
Any better way, please share
